# Laravel 5.7 Nova - The Mix manifest does not exist (on server)

Tags: php, laravel, server, laravel-mix, laravel-nova

I set up laravel Nova locally last night, tested it, used it, everything works great on my local machine.

Uploaded it to the server, and everything works great except when i head to `/nova` which rightfully redirects me to `/nova/login` but then presents me with this error

`The Mix manifest does not exist. (View: /home/loanappboi/nova/resources/views/auth/layout.blade.php)`

i'm using shared hosting, and i uploaded the files to the root, and uploaded the `public` folder content, into `public_html` (i did the necessary file updates to reflect this change)

What could be the cause of this? 
i need help

Answer (score 17):

I got this same error. Running `php artisan nova:publish` fixed it for me. You need to have the nova resources generated.

Answer (score 1):

mix() helper function use `/public/manifest-json.js`

Set it in config

`mix.setPublicPath('public_html/')`

OR

use link to public

`ln -s ./public ./public_html`

For Apache  `Options FollowSymLinks`

Comment: Where should this be set on the server? `mix.setPublicPath('public_html/')`

Comment: setting webpack.mix.js

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are adding '/vendor' in your .gitignore and not 'vendor'. Adding just 'vendor' will ignore all folders named vendor in your codebase and nova resources are in the vendor folder in public folder.